# Firestore Permissions for Chat app

Tags: firebase-security, google-cloud-firestore

Need help with (what seemed like it would be simple) a 1:1 chat use-case.

```
/users/
/users/{userId}/
/users/{userId}/rooms    (this is a Array of References to `Rooms`)
/users/{userId}/first_name
/users/{userId}/last_name
/users/{userId}/last_active

/rooms/
/rooms/{roomId}/
/rooms/{roomId}/created
/rooms/{roomId}/last_updated
/rooms/{roomId}/users    (this is an Array of References to `Users`)
/rooms/{roomId}/messages/...
```

Here are the rules I've been experimenting with. None seem to allow a direct READ on a `room` Document.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /rooms/{roomId=**} { 
      allow read, write: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.isAdmin == true;
      //is it $roomId or roomId? Wouldn't this cause another READ transaction ($++)
      //allow read, write: if $roomId in get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.rooms;
      // is the following even valid?
      allow read, write: if request.auth in resource.data.users;
    }
    match /rooms/{roomId} {
      allow create: if request.auth != null;
    }
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow read, write: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.isAdmin == true;
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
      allow create: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Is `request.auth` not a `users` DocumentReference? The whole rules needs better syntax verification...I'm not even sure if `in` is valid.

Unfortunately there is no client Query (iOS/Swift) for a value within an array so I can't specify "User (reference) `in` `rooms.users`). I have nothing from a `users` to match a string/object in `rooms` so the `isEqualTo` is useless to me.

The easiest solution (I would have thought) would be to limit the READ permissions on the Firestore Rules so when the client performed a `db.collection("rooms").getDocuments()` only the documents which the user would have permission to `read` would populate (`request.auth in resource.data.users`). Apparently this isn't possible.

Or am I way off base and there is a better way to structure the data?

Comment: I guess maybe I'll try to convert the /rooms/users object from an [Reference] to [String] of just raw ids. References aren't allowed for lists: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/security/#list

Comment: Ok that worked. The rule `allow read, write: if request.auth.uid in resource.data.users;` is now being picked up. Any better solutions though?